# How to save an image to a file in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I am new in wpf control and framework. I cant seem to save my images can you help me
Below is my code

```
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(newlist[currentPicture]);                              
            Nullable<bool> result = sfd.ShowDialog();
            if (result == true)
            {

                System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(newlist[currentPicture]);
                bmp.Save(newlist[currentPicture]);
            }
```

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions.

Comment: The three people coincidentally named @SLaks all make solid points.

Comment: @Slank i know the code i wrote is of windowForm but i cant seem to save my BitmapImage. Can you post a code that save a images placed in Wpf Image Control(using System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage)..

Answer (score 3):

For a System.Drawing.Bitmap, you need to pass the dialog's FileName property to the Save method.

**EDIT**: In WPF:

```
var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder()
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(image));
using (var stream = dialog.OpenFile())
    encoder.Save(stream);
```

Comment: Slanks: Can you Explain whats does the last line do ?

Comment: @Pro: See the documentation.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.save.aspx